# ckeditor code snippet addon rails cdn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, cdn

I'm trying to use ckeditor with code snippet. The easiest would be to use the CDN and include it as a script tag. But the default ck editor doesn't have the code snippet plugin. If I download a custom package with code snippet included, then I have to modify all the files to work with Rails asset pipeline, which I don't want to do.

How can I put my own files or as a CDN for free, or find some other low-hassle way to incorporate ckeditor custom packages without having to "railsify" it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use CKEditor official CDN, but use full-all build, which includes all the official CKEditor plugins.

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

And you're good to go. Don't forget to load this plugin, e.g. using [config.extraPlugins](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins). Like so:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    extraPlugins: 'codesnippet'
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Install additional plugins gem 'ckeditor' codesnippet

```
//adding app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/plugins/codesnippet
//app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  config.extraPlugins = 'codesnippet';
}
```

https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#install-additional-plugins

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/codesnippetgeshi

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/codesnippet

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/ajax

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/xml